# Status code: 416, description: 'The range specified is invalid for the current size of the resource.'

Tags: powerbi-desktop

Status code: 416, description: 'The range specified is invalid for the current size of the resource.'. I am getting the above eror while load the data from azure blob storage. can any one help me out.

Answer (score 0):

> Several Blob service GET operations support the use of the standard
> HTTP Range header.
>  Many HTTP clients, including the .NET client
> library, limit the size of the Range header to a 32-bit integer, that
> limits to a maximum of 4 GiB. 
> Since both block blobs and page
> blobs can be larger than 4 GiB in size, the Blob service accepts a
> custom range header x-ms-range for any operation that takes an HTTP
> Range header.

I would suggest to look into [Range Header Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-the-range-header-for-blob-service-operations).

Are you doing it with code or Azure Storage Explorer?